# Conditionnal statement on axis (subplot) and/or on matplotlib.pyplot (plt)

Tags: matplotlib, types, conditional-statements, axis, subplot

I have a function that can take as an argument an axes (class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'). But, if no axes is passed, it will take by default the "plt" object (matplotlib.pyplot). As some methods that applies to axes do not apply to plt, I would like to use a conditionnal statement.

NB : if that is not possible, I will use a try/except statement.

```
def plot1(ax=plt):
    # Ax is a subplot object created before the call to the function
    ax.plot(t1, f(t1))

    if isinstance(ax, module): # <--- this is pseudo-code
    # properties specific to plt object
        ax.title('title')
        ax.xlabel('xlabel')
        ax.ylabel('ylabel')
    else:
    # properties specific to axes object
        ax.set_title('title')
        ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
        ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly advise not to allow for those different input types. This will cause all kinds of problems in case the function becomes a little bit more complicated in the future. Instead, I would let it take only an axes as input, or `None`. In the latter case you can fall back to the current axes.

```
def plot1(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()

    ax.plot(t1, f(t1))
    ax.set_title('title')
    ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
    ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
```

This of course requires to have imported pyplot as `plt` beforehands. If the function is meant to be used in an environment where this cannot be guaranteed, you may still do it on the fly,

```
def plot1(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        ax = plt.gca()

    ax.plot(t1, f(t1))
    ax.set_title('title')
    ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
    ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
```